# slate3k WARNING:pdfminer.layout:Too many boxes (106) to group, skipping

Tags: pdf, pdfminer, slate

I'm trying to extract text from a PDF in python, but I get the following warning message which limits the amount of text for each page that is extracted. Is there any solution anyone can think of to resolve this issue? Code also below:

WARNING:pdfminer.layout:Too many boxes (106) to group, skipping.

```
import slate3k as slate

with open("mypdf.pdf",'rb') as f:
    extracted_text = slate.PDF(f)
print(extracted_text)
```